# Angular Button Reset explanation

Tags: angular

TS Code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() intervalFired = new EventEmitter<number>();
  interval!: NodeJS.Timeout;
  lastNumber = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onStartGame(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() =>{
      this.intervalFired.emit(this.lastNumber + 1);
      this.lastNumber++;
    }, 1000);
  }

  onPauseGame() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  onResetGame() {
    console.log('Game will get refreshed')
    this.interval.refresh
  }
}
```

html code:

```
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onStartGame()">Start game</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onPauseGame()">Stop the game</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onResetGame()">Reset the game</button>
</div>
```

I want to make a reset button i'm new to programming and angular and i couldnt find what i was searching for. Would love any example not sure if thats the right way to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your `interval`, reset the number and set again the `interval` by calling `onGameStart` method

```
onResetGame() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.lastNumber = 0;
    this.onStartGame();
}
```

`clearInterval()` is also from `NodeJS.Timeout`

Comment: I ve added it to my code, thank you ! 
Is it possible to make it clear everything that was outputted on the screen when i press that button ? I'm asking cause it just starts counting again and is not clearing earlier outputs

Comment: For that, you should share more code, especially from your template to understand how you display it